# Html5shiv not working

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, html5shiv

I´ve a problem with the html5shiv script. It´s not working in ie8>-

[Preview here:](http://www.halberstadtwerke.de/bk14test)
This Script is in Use:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

already tested:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.createElement('header')
    document.createElement('footer')
    document.createElement('main')
    document.createElement('section')
    document.createElement('nav')
</script>
```

Load the script in the HEAD - AFTER and BEFORE the styles.

All html5 elements have this standard styles:
(load after both scripts)

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { display: block; }
audio, canvas, video { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
[hidden] { display: none; }
```

Unfortunately not found any suitable solution on google, stackoverflow and the html5shiv documentation site. Tried all Tipps/Tricks from the answers here. But it´s still not working.

Comment: I assume there is some issue with your copy/paste. Take a backup and copy/paste it again and hopefully your problem shall be resolved. - @rivadaice

Comment: please change "scrollChange: false," to "scrollChange: false" in http://www.halberstadtwerke.de/bk14test/scripts/jquery.nav.js on line number 48.

Comment: media query not work in " lt ie 9 ".

Comment: @vipul : thats what it is for...to support modern tags!! :)

Comment: Thanks htmlshiv works. I will try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125905/responsive-site-not-working-in-ie-despite-css3-mediaqueries-js

Thanks for your help and have a nice weekend/day.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125905/responsive-site-not-working-in-ie-despite-css3-mediaqueries-js

That´s it all works perfectly!! Thanks to the Stackoverflowcommunity. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try using Shivs on bottom or change the location. Sometimes they just conflict with Js.!

Answer (score 0):

Is your stylesheet loading from the current domain, not an off-site CDN or anything like that?  If the stylesheet is hosted elsewhere, host it locally on your domain and see if that helps.